# sha256 hashing algorithm on objective c fails to create a hash that matches the hash generated on the server

Tags: objective-c, hash, sha256

I am using the following code to create a sha256 hash of a file, that gets compared against a hash created downstream.
The hash created by my code appears to fail very intermittently.

```
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

if ( CC_SHA256([data bytes], [data length], hash) ) {

    NSData *sha256 = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];


    NSString *hash=[sha256 description];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    return hash;
}
return nil;
```

Hope someone can help me with this? The hash gets generated properly 99.9% of the time, but does fails rarely.

Edit:
to clarify, 
The hash generated on my code is the same as the hash generated by the server most of the time.
intermittently, however, the hash generated does not match the one generated downstream.
We checked the file with one of the online hashing sites, and the hash generated by the server was correct, while mine did not match the hash generated by the site(defuse.ca)

Comment: _The hash created by my code appears to fail very intermittently_ is an adequate problem description for, um, nothing.

Comment: Can you please describe what "fails" means in this situation?

Comment: when i say fail, i meant that the hash fails to match the hash generated by the equivalent server side code

Comment: When you read the file did you check that if the line endings of the file was proper on your machine and the one that was used to create the hash on the server? Is exactly the same file being used to generate the hash on the server and at the app end? May be when transferring the file some kind of end of line conversion may be happening.

Comment: that is something that i am checking now- to see if the problem was not with the code but with the file getting replaced. waiting for the file to be given to us. this occurs so randomly and till now, my downstream serer has been throwing away all files that do not match till now.

Comment: It looks like you are using a function ( with a message digest on the `Stack`).  In the `man CC_SHA256` the `message digest` is a `unsigned char *`.  Have you tried `unsigned char *messageDigest = malloc(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);`?  Using this method you are asking for a `heap` variable.  This worked for me.

Comment: @roberto's answer also worked for me when I used the `unsigned int byte array`.  Here: `uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH]={0};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an category to the NSData class with this function and use this instead of description. Also check the case of the hex strings between this string and the one on the server side.

```
-(NSString *)hexEncodedString
{
    unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char*)[self bytes];    
    NSInteger length = [self length];
    NSMutableString *hexEncodedString = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        [hexEncodedString appendFormat:@"%0.2x", bytes[i]];
    }
    return hexEncodedString;
}
```

Comment: accepting this as the answer, though it has not been solved yet. will try this and hope the problem is not replicated again. :-(

Comment: If it doesnt work let me know. Pass me the sample source andnserver hashed string as well if it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean with failing, but this works fine for me:

```
    NSString *pword=@"My text to apply hash";

    const char *s=[pword cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData=[NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH]={0};

    CC_SHA256(keyData.bytes, (CC_LONG)keyData.length, digest);

    NSData *out=[NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    NSString *hashData=[out description];
    hashData = [hashData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    hashData = [hashData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    hashData = [hashData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    return hashData;
```

Comment: that appears to be the same code that i am using...and like i said, the code works 99 times out of 1000 and fails to match the hash generated by the java code taht one time...

Comment: Is the file downloaded from the server by your app and then hash created and matched against the one on the server? Check if the file that was downloaded and from which hash is created by your code matches exactly the file that's on the server.

Comment: er- 999/1000. no file is generated on my device and sent to the server.

Comment: sorry about the delay in answering pradeep- the file, as far as we can see, is the same. the hashing algorithm used by us creates a hash that matches the one created by the server 99% of the time. one of the times it did not, we took the file, and checked the hash- it matched the hsh generated by the server. we do not have the file on the ipad. i will be working on this at a later date, as it is near impossible to replicate. thank you for your help.